# Sculpt mode problem

Tags: sculpting

[image]I am a newbie and i am doing the Blender Guru's doughnut tutorial (part 5 level 1) and i am trying to sculpt the doughnut but it isn't working. It only works for the icing. I think it doesn't recognise the doughnut being able to be sculpted. If anyone knows hoe to fix it or why it is happened then please reply to this message. Thank You

Comment: Can you add an image or something please?

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you could check. Sometimes Sculpt Mode doesn't like your modifiers, and they would then need to be applied before sculpting. More likely, though, your normals are reversed. You can reverse them in Edit Mode automatically by selecting all your faces, and then pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd>.

Another thing that should be done before sculpting is applying all your transforms in Object Mode, with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> . But this isn't needed to fix your exact problem. Rather, it merely prevents unpredictable distortion weirdness from taking place when you sculpt.

It might be worth pointing out that if your icing and doughnut are separate objects, then only the most recently selected one will be the one to receive sculpting edits. You can only sculpt on one object at a time, and you have to manually switch between them before doing so. Switching between them typically takes place in Object Mode. That said, there is a way to change this behavior so that you don't have to switch modes in order to target various entities of whatever type.  The feature is called *Lock Object Modes*, and it's located under the *Edit* Menu at the top left of the screen. Uncheck it, and you should be able to alternate which of your objects is selected and available for sculpting, all without leaving Sculpt Mode to change the selection.